# How to save YouTube video link in SQL Server database using C#

Tags: sql, database, hyperlink, youtube, store

I am developing a website project  using C#, a. How can I save YouTube video link in MSSQL database ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for it:

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/06/21/save-and-display-youtube-video-links-on-asp-net-website.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1104451.aspx/1?How+to+retrieve+video+file+from+sql+server+database http://www.saurabhdeveloper.com/techtips_details.php?tipsid=15 http://forums.asp.net/p/1533758/3719583.aspx http://forums.asp.net/t/1045855.aspx/2/10 http://forums.asp.net/t/1511588.aspx/1 http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/274821-Play-video-file-asp-net-page.aspx http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/kfra/archive/2006/10/04/50003.aspx http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/16239-code-for-video-upload.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/88899/ http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/10-working-with-video

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/88899/